# Cannot load compiled class after compilation

Tags: clojure, compilation, classpath

I've searched a lot, and I found quite a lot of answers, which indicates it is a "popular" problem... nevertheless, I can't solve it.

I can successfully compile a class. In order to do this, I have this bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [[ $CLASSPATH ]] ; then
    extra_classpath=""
else
    extra_classpath=":$CLASSPATH"
fi

while true ; do
    case "$1" in
        -cp | -classpath)
            extra_classpath=":$2"
            shift 2 ;;
        --)
            shift
            break ;;
        *)
            break ;;
    esac
done

java -cp /usr/share/java/clojure.jar:./classes/:./src/"$extra_classpath" \
clojure.main "$@"
```

This is basically a remake of what is installed by default with closure on Debian, only added the local directories to the classpath.

When I start REPL this way, I can then do:

```
user=> (compile 'tld.assignment.sum_calculator)
```

The class-files are generated in the ./classes/tld.assignment.sum_calculator

But I can't load what was compiled. I've tried to run this script with the fully qualified class name as an argument - I get file not found. If I run java like this:

```
$ java -cp /usr/share/java/clojure.jar:./classes/ \
tld.assignment.sum_calculator 1 2
```

Also, immediately from REPL I tried `(load "tld.assignment.sum_calculator")` with file extension and without, with dots replaced by slashes and with leading dot and all to no effect - `(load)` always "succeeds", returns nil and there it ends :S

I get class def not found. I'm clueless what is going wrong. :(

**EDIT:**

Sorry for the noise, one successful permutation of the path made it. I've no idea why, but if I swap the ./classes/ directory with the clojure.jar on the classpath, then it works... Java...

Answer (score 0):

No need to answer this really. It looks like some bug in the path expansion (?) or in the way Java loader reads the path... anyway, it's solved for now.